# Destroy/Show an array element with link_to function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a model with an array column ("Product_list") and would like to ***delete/show an array element through a controller*** when a user selects an array element in the view.

*Delete will give a confirmation prompt and remove the selected array element from the same view.

*Show will lead the user to another page where the product details in another data table associated with the user-selected array element will be shown)

I just put ???????? in link_to lines since I don't know what path I can use for an array element. I've also excluded SHOW and DESTROY actions from the controller since I just don't know what to put there.

Index.html.erb

```
<% @product.product_list.each do |list| %>
  <%= link_to(list) do %>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
      <p><%= list %></p>
      <%= link_to 'Show Details', ????????? %>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', ??????????, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Products_controller.rb

```
def index
  @product = Product.find(current_user.product)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end

def new
  @product = Product.new
end

def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.save
  Product.find_by_sql(["UPDATE products SET product_list = array_append(product_list, ?) WHERE user_id = ?", params[:product][:product_list], current_user]);
end
```

Model

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "product_list", default: [], array: true
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "products", ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to 'Show Details', product_path(id: @product.id, array_element: list) %>
<%= link_to 'Destroy', product_path(id: @product.id, array_element: list), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And in your controller for show and destroy, check for param :array_element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it gives an error: "No route matches {:action=>"show", :array_element=>"", :controller=>"products", :product_id=>24} missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: Perhaps I am not setting up param :array_element in the controller... An array element the user selects should be saved to that param but I am not sure if "@product.product_list.each do |list|" in the view gets passed to the controller so that "list" can be used in the controller...

Answer (score 1):

## Understanding rails routes

When you use the erb `link_to` method, you are basically creating a normal link, same as using:

`<a href="/"></a>`

But instead of indicating the normal url path *(in the case of the normal link, the url destination would be inside `href`)*, you need to declare it the rails path, you declare your rails paths in your routes.rb file.

If you want to know what are your rails paths, you need to run:

`rake routes`

In your Terminal, and that command will print your current rails routes.

Here is an example of the output:

[image]

As you can see, the URI Pattern is the normal path, but if you see the prefix, you can see the rails path, for example:

`new_user_session` does `devise/sessions#new` that goes to `/users/sign_in`

To use that rails path, you need to include "path" at the end of the prefix.

Example:

`new_user_session_path`

So the end result would be:

`<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>`

## CRUD and the controller

CRUD stands for **Create**, **Read**, **Update** and **Destroy**.

Those actions are self-explanatory, and you write them in your controller.

For example, if you have a list of products in your index view, this is the code for the products_controller:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

And you want to show in your index each of the elements that `Product.all` returns (and stores in the variable `@products`) you just need to write this in your index view:

```
<% @products.each do |f| %>
  <%= link_to "#{f.name}", f %>
  </br>
<% end %>
```

In the code above, rails automatically recognises that you want to go to the instance of each element in the ruby block, in this case `f`, so you just need to write `f` instead of the prefix_path (remember?)

Now, that will print all the product names and make them a link (thanks to `link_to`) to the corresponding path (url), and to show each single instance of the `@products` variable (returned by `Product.all`) you need to write the following code in the show method in your products_controller.rb file:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

That references each of the product to the proper id, (/products/1/ ... /102/) and so on.

So now when you click on each instance, it will render the corresponding product found by it's id (see the show method), now, if you want to delete an specific product, it's simple, add this code to your products_controller:

```
def destroy
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if @product.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Product was deleted successfully."
    redirect_to products_path
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the product. Please try again."
    render :show
  end
end
```

<sub>*Note: in order to make the flash messages work, you need to enable them in your application, but because it's beyond the scope of the question I'm not going to go through it for now.*</sub>

As you can see, the code is very readable and self-explanatory, when delete the product it will destroy it, show a flash message and then rendering the proper path.

In your show.html.erb view file, you need to have the following code in order to delete the record (in this case the product, because of the show method that returns a product based on it's id), here's the example code:

```
<%= "#{@product.name}" %>
</br>
<%= "#{@product.description}" %>

<%= link_to "Delete product", @product, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this product?' } %>
```

That will destroy the product instance from the database (if you click the link) because that fire up the destroy action in your products_controller.

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: Quite complete answer  I think nowadays `link_to` won't work with the delete method, you'll need to use `button_to`.